# Object.keys is not efficient if key is instance of RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, key, object-literal

```js
let ob = {};
ob[/\ing?$/] = `I match all strings end with "ing"`; //key is instance of 'RegEXp'
ob["/\ing?$/"] = `I am sure it is not same as the above`; //key is instance of 'String'

console.log(
`- Key RegExp :
   ==> ${ob[/\ing?$/]}
`);

console.log(
`- Key String :
   ==> ${ob["/\ing?$/"]}
`);
```

The above string demonstrates that literal object property can be an instance of `RegExp` class and it can be also `String` of course and they are totally different .

My question is how to check if the type property using `Object.keys` or alternative . Known that using `Object.keys`, this method casts all keys (properties) to string ?

```
Object.keys(ob);
 //--> Expected :[/\ing?$/, "/\ing?$/"]
 //--> Actual : ["/\ing?$/", "/ing?$/"]
```

Comment: You cannot use Objects, you can use array to store regex.

Comment: Object key will be converted to string.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `key is instance of 'RegEXp'` - are you sure about that? `typeof` disagrees with your assertion

Comment: Does the `RegExp` match the example string?

Answer (score 2):

Property names are always strings. If you try to use something else as a property name, it will be converted to a string using `toString()`. So when you do:

```
ob[/\ing?$/] = `I match all strings end with "ing"`; //key is instance of 'RegEXp';
```

it's treated as

```
ob[/\ing?$/.toString()] = `I match all strings end with "ing"`; //key is instance of 'RegEXp';
```

So the key is `"/\ing?$/"`.

When you do:

```
ob["/\ing?$/"] = `I am sure it is not same as the above`; //key is instance of 'String';
```

the key is the string `"/ing?$/"`. The backslash is gone because in a string literal, backslash is an escape character. `\i` just escapes the `i` character, but since `i` has no special meaning, it's just `i`.

If you wanted to get the same key as from the RegExp, it should be:

```
ob["/\\ing?$/"] = `I am sure it is not same as the above`; //key is instance of 'String';
```

The double backslash escapes the backslash, so it gets put into the string literally.

```js
let ob = {};
ob[/\ing?$/] = `I match all strings end with "ing"`; //key is instance of 'RegEXp';
ob["/\\ing?$/"] = `I am sure it is not same as the above`; //key is instance of 'String';
console.log(ob);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The above string demonstrates that literal object property can be an instance of RegExp class

That is wrong. All object keys are `string`. Anything that is not string will be converted to string. The proof can be seen in code sample below. Although `o1` and `o2` are different, they both have same string representation and can be used to access the property of `o`.

```js
var o1 = {};
o1.toString = function(){return "I am unique";};

var o2 = {};
o2.toString = function(){return "I am unique";};


var o = {};
o[o1] = "foo";



console.log(o[o2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties are being converted to strings when they're set:

```
for (var key in ob) {
    console.log('key', key, 'type', typeof key);
}

> key /\ing?$/ type string
> key /ing?$/ type string
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RegExp` at `javascript` at Question does not match the example string.

```js
let re = /\ing?$/;
console.log(re.test(`I match all strings end with "ing"`));
```

You can use `RegExp` `/(.|)ing?(\1|\.)$/` to match string ending with `ing` or `ing.`, or `"ing"` define property and value of object as `RegExp`

```js
const re = /(.|)ing?(\1|\.)$/;

let ob = {[re]:re};

console.log(ob[re].test(`I match all strings end with "ing"`));

console.log(ob[re].test(`I match all strings end with ing.`));

console.log(ob[re].test(`I match all strings end with ing`));

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(ob));

for (let {[re]:regexp} of [ob]) {
  console.log(regexp instanceof RegExp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am the  owner of question, The best solution that i noticed is to change the data structure from literal object to array :

## From :

```
ob = {
   /\ing?$/ : `I match all strings end with "ing"`,
  "/\ing?$/" : `I am sure it is not same as the above`
};
```

## to :

```
ob = [

   {key: /\ing?$/ , value: `I match all strings end with "ing"` },
   {key:"/\ing?$/" , value: `I am sure it is not same as the above` },  
]
```

By that, we conserve the type of key if it is `RegExp` instance.